# Linux/KDE - How to stop trackpad cursor jumping when scrolling with one finger and clickin with thumb

Tags: linux, mouse, touchpad, kde, scrolling

I like to scroll with my index finger and click with my thumb in the lower half of the trackpad (rather than tapping, I like to actually click).

Quite often when I do this, the cursor will jump to the lower left corner of the screen because it detects my finger seemingly moving incredibly fast from wherever it is to the lower left part of the trackpad, when in fact it's two different fingers.

Is there a way I can avoid this?